# How do you target an element deep inside multiple elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If you have the following html:

```
<div class="example">
 <div>
   <div>
     <div>
      <span></span>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can you target that specific span inside ".example"? without having to write

```
$('.example div div div span')
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Unless there are other spans in the tree it's just $('.example span'), butI'm sure there's more to your question

Comment: add a class on the element you will want to target would be the simplest

Comment: are there other `span`s in `.example`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to specify all the nesting. In css selector space means *any descendant of*, not *direct child*. So it should be just

```
$('.example span')
```

On the other hand, you might want to restrict the search results by specifiying which `span` exactly do you want. In this case, you would want to set class or id attribute on that span and search for it, using

```
$('.example span#spanid') //for id = spanid
$('.example span.spanclass') //for class = spanclass
```

See [W3C selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) document for details

Answer (score 3):

`$('.example span')` should also find it.

Answer (score 1):

While both previous answers are perfectly valid and answer the question, I'd suggest that if possible you add a class to the nested element(s) you want to find instead. There aren't any direct performance improvements to this, merely semantics and clarity. For example,

```
$('.example span')
```

may work for now, but if you add other spans later, it'll break. However, if you add .my_nested_span to the span you want and then do

```
$('.my_nested_span')
```

instead, you should always be good to go in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the span an id:

```
<span id="myspan"></span>
```

And then it's simply:

```
$('#myspan')
```